# Legal status of telecommute work in Mexico (with a temporary resident status)

Tags: freelance, mexico

Is it officially allowed for a resident alien in Mexico (temporary resident, not allowed to work for Mexican companies) to provide services as a remote worker to the companies outside Mexico? I've asked several several attorneys and checked several sources in the internet and they all give different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we applied for residency before moving to Mexico from New Zealand in 2016 we asked the consulate (during our interviews) about the need for work permits and explained that I wanted to work remotely for a NZ company. The Mexican consulate told me that was my only option, they had not approved me for a work permit under the Residente Temporal, so could not work for a Mexico company or be paid into a Mexico bank account. However they said they had no problem with my working remotely for a company outside of Mexico as long as I was paid into a bank account also outside of Mexico.

When we arrived in Mexico and had to finish the residency permit requirements the immigration officers here reiterated the same restrictions.

See also a similar question I asked here, and the follow up answer I added once we had settled - [Remote international contract work - visa requirements](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/8629/9277)

Comment: Thanks. May I ask if you also know what are the income tax regulations for this income?

Comment: @Khirange, You need to ask a lawyer about that. If you are a tax resident of Mexico the income is taxable, but "resident" for tax purposes isn't the same as "resident" for immigration purposes. If you have little or no Mexican income and can argue that your primary home and "vital center of interests" is elsewhere you might escape taxes, otherwise you'll owe them. A lawyer would have an informed opinion.

Comment: @Dennis, it's always better to get information from several sources, and lawyers here don't really know much about the situations like this. Escaping taxes isn't something what I'd like to do, as you just _have_ to pay income taxes somewhere, and if you don't you're probably going to have problems sooner or later.