# IMSS mandatory when working remotely from Mexico for a foreign company?

Tags: health-insurance, social-security, mexico

If I am employed (as a regular employee, not as a contractor) by a German, or generally by a foreign company, which does not have a subsidiary in Mexico, and work for them remotely while living in Mexico, does my company have to register me in the Mexican social security system for employees (IMSS)?

I am aware that I would have to pay income tax in Mexico, but the information that I found about the social security system was not so clear. I am planning to get private health insurance anyway, so I'd prefer not to participate in the IMSS.

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/legal-status-of-telecommute-work-in-mexico-with-a-temporary-resident-status

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/remote-international-contract-work-visa-requirements

Comment: When I moved here (Mexico) from NZ I asked about working remotely - basically they said as long as I wasn't employed by a Mexico company and wasn't paid into a Mexico bank account then I wouldn't need a work visa (they wouldn't give me one) and would effectively be employed in a different country.  The two links above expand on my experience

Comment: Hi @Midavalo! Thank you for the links! I had found those already. But as I understood, you are working as a contractor for an organization in NZ. Do you know if the same rules apply to regular employees?

Comment: @Tobias, I'm pretty positive that for immigration purposes your exact relationship with a foreign employer is irrelevant. If your employer isn't Mexican and you aren't being paid in MX$ then you aren't working in Mexico. Similarly, I understand IMSS participation is only mandatory if you are formally employed by a Mexican employer, otherwise participation is voluntary (and there is no mandate requiring the foreign employer to contribute just because you live in Mexico).

Comment: Tobias - as @Dennis has said, the Mexico consulate didn't care about the arrangement with the employer, just that I was not allowed to work for a Mexico company nor get paid into a Mexico account.

Comment: @Tobias, have you resolved your question? Do you pay taxes in Mexico and how?

Comment: @Suncatcher, I have not resolved the question because in the end I went to Spain instead of Mexico.